# Executing 32-bit binary

Tags: 32-bit

How do I execute a 32 binary? I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. When I try to I get an error message like:

```
/usr/local/bin/y10: No such file or directory
```

Even though:

```
file /usr/local/bin/y10
/usr/local/bin/y10: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, not stripped
```

Comment: Unless you know what 32bit libraries the software needs (and in turn can install them) you aren't going to be able to run the software.

Comment: The readelf -d  command will list the needed libraries for a 32 bit executable.